# property Manager

Tags: professionalism, management, salary

I started my new position 15 days ago in a reputable company back in Saudi Arabia. Now HR has offered me a low package salary. After negotiating with them I managed to get 20% more and I accepted and started working. However my basic salary is still 40% less than my minimum expectation.

I have 70 days left to finish the 3 months probation period. How can I get the best package salary?

Comment: Any place I've worked compensation is agreed at hire time.  It would be very unusual to start negotiations 15 days into the job and expect renegotiation at the end of probation.

Comment: Well, you probably shouldn't have accepted the low offer in the first place.

Comment: @salem, welcome to http://workplace.stackexchange.com/  The situation you're describing seems very unique. You may want to add additional context, such as why salary is being negotiated 15 days into your job as opposed to prior to acceptance.

Answer (score 3):

By finding a new job, and negotiating your package **before** you do anything for them.

Not knowing your salary until two weeks into the job is a waste of your time, and a signal to the employer that you're desperate.

They have no incentive to offer you anything more; you already showed that you're okay with just half your desired salary level.

Start looking for another role elsewhere. This time, state your minimum and don't work until you've got it ensured on paper.